# Mysql date_add returns wrong row in python, right row in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, timestamp, python

I am trying to get the first and last record from a month.  In phpmyadmin I ge the correct result.  In python I don't.  In fact python returns the same row for both of these queries.  First number is the table primary key for the rows.

```
SELECT * 
FROM mcs 
WHERE time_stamp < DATE_ADD( DATE_ADD( LAST_DAY( NOW( ) ) , 
                                       INTERVAL 25 HOUR ) , 
                             INTERVAL -2 MONTH) 
  AND wot_id = 1010965979
LIMIT 1

838831, '1010965979', datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 6, 22, 0), Decimal('444.88'), Decimal('0.00')

SELECT * 
FROM mcs 
WHERE time_stamp < DATE_ADD( DATE_ADD( LAST_DAY( NOW( ) ) , 
                                       INTERVAL 24 HOUR ) , 
                             INTERVAL -1 MONTH)
  AND wot_id = 1010965979 
LIMIT 1

838831, '1010965979', datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 6, 22, 0), Decimal('444.88'), Decimal('0.00')
```

phpmyadmin shows this row for the first query,

839037 1010965979 2015-04-01 00:00:00 437.36 0.00

and this for the second:

953868 1010965979 2015-04-30 23:00:00 479.67 0.00

using MySQLdb and python 3

What is wrong?  is this a bug in MySQLdb?  I would not think so as it just passing a SQL string to mysql

Comment: `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY` does not guarantee consistent results.

Comment: And that should be `24 HOUR`, not 25 !

Comment: I was using 25 because I am using < , so thje 25 hours made it 0:0 hours on first day of the month, so less thaan that included last hour of last day of last month.  Does that make sense?  My time_stamp is limiteds to hours, all min and sec are 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, a crucial mistake of the queries:

- **`LIMIT` without `ORDER BY` does not guarantee consistent results.**
- If you get correct results using `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY`, **it's only by accident**.

The results you got from running the queries in PHPMyAdmin was only accidental. There is no guarantee that you'll get the same results if you run the same queries tomorrow.

Adding `ORDER BY` (either `ASC` or `DESC`) will solve the issue.

There is also another problem with the 1st query. Adding 25 hours instead of 24 might be a nice hack - if it worked. It might work with the current data but it will stop, if there are ever rows that are not limited to full hours or there are no rows for the first hour of a month. You need to use 24 hours (or 1 day) and `timestamp >= ...` and `ORDER BY .. ASC` to get the first row from a period.

Queries rewritten (I used date arithmetic instead of your `DATE_ADD()`, this is entirely personal preference, the `DATE_ADD()` is fine in your queries):

```
-- First row in previous month (or later)
SELECT * 
FROM mcs 
WHERE time_stamp >= LAST_DAY(NOW()) + INTERVAL 1 DAY + INTERVAL -2 MONTH 
  AND wot_id = 1010965979
ORDER BY time_stamp ASC
LIMIT 1 ;

-- Last row in previous month (or earlier)
SELECT * 
FROM mcs 
WHERE time_stamp <  LAST_DAY(NOW()) + INTERVAL 1 DAY + INTERVAL -1 MONTH 
  AND wot_id = 1010965979
ORDER BY time_stamp DESC 
LIMIT 1 ;
```

Comment: ticked this as answer as it explains why my "stumbled on this solution" actually works.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by adding

ORDER BY time_stamp DESC LIMIT 1

to the SQL.  Must have been a silent 'order by' inserted by PHPmyadmin?

Comment: Adding `ORDER BY` is correct, you should never have `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY`, unless you don't mind inconsistent result. About the explanation, you are wrong. PHPMyAdmin does not add an `order by`, the results you show there, were only by accident what you wanted.